# Exception while unmarshalling Java

Tags: java, exception, jaxb

Helo! Please, help me to solve exception **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: I/O exception saving generated file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: com\sun\proxy\$Proxy0.class** 
I need to unmarshall this class with attributes properly.

Here we have my class implementation

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "mail_settings_document" )
@XmlType(propOrder = { "senderMail", "SMTPHostServer" , "SMTPPort" , "login" ,    "password" , "encryption"})
public class TMailDocument extends TDocument implements IMailDocument {


// --------------------- [ КОНСТРУКТОР КЛАССА ] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public TMailDocument() {}

public TMailDocument( String path, IDocumentAction action ) { super( path, action ); }

// --------------------- [ КОНСТРУКТОР КЛАССА ] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



// --------------------- [ ПРИВАТНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ ] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**  святая святых - параметры почты
 */

@XmlElement(name = "SENDER_MAIL")
private String senderMail = "";

@XmlElement(name = "SMTP_SERVER")
private String SMTPHostServer = "";

@XmlElement(name = "SMTP_PORT")
private String SMTPPort = "";

@XmlElement(name = "LOGIN")
private String login = "";

@XmlElement(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password = "";


@XmlElement(name = "ENCRYPTION", type = ENCRYPTION_TYPE.class)
private ENCRYPTION_TYPE encryption = ENCRYPTION_TYPE.UNKNOWN;

// --------------------- [ ПРИВАТНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ ] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



// --------------------- [ ПУБЛИЧНЫЕ МЕТОДЫ КЛАССА ] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public String name() { return this.getClass().getSimpleName(); }


/**  геттеры и сеттеры параметров почты
 */


@Override
public String getSMTPHostServer() { return SMTPHostServer;  }

@Override
public String getSenderMail() { return senderMail; }

@Override
public String getSMTPPort() { return SMTPPort;  }

@Override
public String getLogin() { return login; }

@Override
public String getPassword() { return password; }

@Override
public ENCRYPTION_TYPE getEncryption() { return encryption; }




@Override
@XmlTransient
public IDocument setEncryption(ENCRYPTION_TYPE encryption) {
    if ( encryption != null ) { this.encryption = encryption; }
    return this;
}

@Override
@XmlTransient
public IDocument setSenderMail ( String from )
{
    if ( from != null ) { this.senderMail = from; }
    return this;
}

@Override
@XmlTransient
public IDocument setSMTPHostServer ( String host ) throws Exception
{
    if ( host!= null ) { SMTPHostServer = host; }
    return this;
}

@Override
@XmlTransient
public IDocument setSMTPPort ( String port ) throws Exception
{
    if ( port!= null ) { SMTPPort = port; }
    return this;
}

@Override
@XmlTransient
public IDocument setLogin ( String login ) throws Exception
{

    if ( login!= null ) { this.login  = login; }
    return this;

}

@Override
@XmlTransient
public IDocument setPassword ( String pass ) throws Exception
{
    if ( pass!= null ) { password  = pass; }
    return this;

}
}
```

And my class interface:

```
 public interface IMailDocument {

/** перечисление:какой тип шифрования используется
 *  UNKNOWN - пустое значение
 *  SSL - SSl
 *  TLS - TLS
 *  NONE - без шифрования
 */
public enum ENCRYPTION_TYPE
{
    UNKNOWN,SSL,TLS,NONE;

    public boolean isUnknown()
    {
        return this.equals(UNKNOWN);
    }

};

// --------------------- [ ПУБЛИЧНЫЕ МЕТОДЫ КЛАССА ] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/** свойство:метод: получение сервера
 */
public String getSMTPHostServer();

/** свойство:метод: получение адреса отправителя
 */
public String getSenderMail();

/** свойство:метод: получение порта севрера
 */
public String getSMTPPort();

/** свойство:метод: получение логина
 */
public String getLogin();

/** свойство:метод: получение пароля
 */
public String getPassword();

/** свойство:метод: тип шифрвоания подключения
 */
public TMailDocument.ENCRYPTION_TYPE getEncryption();

/** метод: устанвока шифрования
 */
public IDocument setEncryption(ENCRYPTION_TYPE encryption);

/** метод: устанвока почты отпраивтеля
 */
public IDocument setSenderMail ( String from );

/** метод: установка сервера
 */
public IDocument setSMTPHostServer ( String host ) throws Exception;

/** метод: установка порта севрера
 */
public IDocument setSMTPPort ( String port ) throws Exception ;

/** метод: установка логина
 */
public IDocument setLogin ( String login ) throws Exception ;

/** метод: установка пароля
 */
public IDocument setPassword ( String pass ) throws Exception ;
}
```

PS All files are in proper path and **marshalling** goes well

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: I/O exception saving generated file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: com\sun\proxy\$Proxy0.class (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at XDocumentFactory.XMLDocumentIO.loadXML(XMLDocumentIO.java:146)
    at XDocumentFactory.DocumentLoader.loadDocument(DocumentLoader.java:62)
    at XDocumentFactory.DocumentFactory.loadDocument(DocumentFactory.java:89)
    at XMailMessanger.MailMessenger.loadSettings(MailMessenger.java:158)
    at alfa.runner.main(runner.java:24)
```

Comment: Just a guess, could it be related to the fact that all your setters are marked @XmlTransient?

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace of the error?

Comment: i will post it in Answer

Comment: exception throws in **JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TMailDocument.class);**

Comment: It seems that the application can't save a runtime generated class ...  I don't know, just check if your application have write permission ... no more ideas. успехов

Comment: I strongly believe that some jar file got corrupted (This is just a case, since this is a unique problem). If i were you I would delete my target folder where classes are compiled. if this does not work then I will download dependencies again and start from clean compile. if nothing works then I will write small sample project and try to do the same. If that doesn't work then I will download one small sample project and run it and see if that works. These steps will definitely takes you to some solution. And if you find your problem please let every one know what was wrong.

Comment: Problem solved by first **Marshalling** and only the second - **UnMarshelling**

Answer (score 1):

```
-Dsun.misc.ProxyGenerator.saveGeneratedFiles=false
```

or

```
try {
  final Field field = ProxyGenerator.class.getDeclaredField("saveGeneratedFiles");
  final boolean isAccessible = field.isAccessible();
  if (!isAccessible)
    field.setAccessible(true);
  final Field modifiers = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
  modifiers.setAccessible(true);
  modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
  modifiers.setAccessible(false);
  field.setBoolean(null, false);
  if (!isAccessible)
    field.setAccessible(false);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```